# How to get the width and height of a BitmapImage in metro (UWP)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, microsoft-metro, bitmapimage

I'm working in metro applications.

And I'm using `BitmapImage`, where since the constructor I set the `Uri`, but I realized that all the time `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` returns `0` (I've verified also that the `Uri` is correct).

I can't find another class which returns me those properties. I was thinking if there's a way to get those data through a byte array or something like that. What do you think?

Comment: Assuming you're loading from the local file system/resource, try waiting until the next main thread loop for the bitmap to load in.  If it's from a network/internet source, you may need to wait for a bit longer while it downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the CacheOption property and set to BitmapCacheOption.None. You can also try convert to  a WriteableBitmap.
If what I said is not true, sorry, because I can not test on. Xaml (wpf only) xD

Comment: I've set CacheOption to BitmapCacheOption.None and it didn't work

Comment: Remember you must change the BitmapCache before passing the image to the source. Well then try to cast a WriteableBitmap....

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapImage` returns `0` for `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` if the image isn't loaded. The image is only loaded when it's actually used, for example, assigned to `Image.Source` and displayed. That's... problematic. Using `BitmapCacheOption.None` doesn't help, it only worked on WP7.

The right solution is to use `BitmapDecoder`:

```
var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
var size = new BitmapSize { Width = decoder.PixelWidth, Height = decoder.PixelHeight };
```

Found [this solution on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ebfb789-040d-4b9d-8969-1135d3b62b17/pixelwidth-and-pixelheight-return-zero).